# Firefox on Ubuntu spell checks with British dictionary

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, dictionary

I am an Ubuntu User (20.4), but this has been happening since I first switched to Ubuntu a year or so ago (19.10 at the time). When typing into text boxes in Firefox, occasionally, a word will be marked wrong, only to attempt to correct it with the British spelling (specifically, I've noticed this with the words behavior/behaviour, analyzed/analysed). Interestingly, as I type, (on Firefox), the British spelled versions of these words are highlighted as incorrect. Here are the different combinations I've tried.

- Firefox, LinkedIn -> British spelling preferred
- Chrome, LinkedIn -> US spelling preferred
- Firefox, Superuser -> US spelling preferred
- Chrome, Superuser -> US spelling preferred for behavior, but not flagged at all for analyzed/analysed

Generally, this isn't an issue, but as I'm spending much of my time writing cover letters, updating my resume, and posting to LinkedIn, I prefer to have an accurate dictionary by my side. That being said, at this point, I'm also genuinely curious why this is happening.

Any insights are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Any insights are appreciated!

On Firefox you can right click in any text field to set the spell check `Language` and whether `Check Spelling` is enabled. This setting is site specific.

On Super User I have:

> [image]

Here I changed Language some time ago from US to UK.

On Meta Stack Exchange I have:

> [image]

I don't recall changing the settings on Meta.

I rarely use Chrome so I haven't looked at language settings there, but there is probably some site specific configuration option.

> not flagged at all for analyzed/analysed

On Firefox, if Check Spelling is not enabled it won't flag. If it is enabled then it flags:

> [image]

Comment: This is the answer. It looks like for some reason, Firefox decided to set my spell checker to UK. I don't recall doing this, but who knows *shrug.* Thanks for the help!